# "Access Denied" on Vista shared folder from SBS 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, file-sharing, share

I have Windows Server 2003 SBS and one user has Windows Vista installed. I have shared some files on that Vista machine and I'd like to access them from the SBS 2003 server, but I get an "Access denied" message.

I have granted full permissions to the share folders. When I restart the Vista system for some time I can access that folder, but after some time it disconnects automatically. I have done all that I think is needed. I've also turned off the Windows firewall and then tried it, but the same problem persists.

The user is a domain user with full admin rights. Any insight into resolving this problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure that the time is in sync between the server and the Vista machine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have given the permissions under the Sharing tab in the folder properties dialog and not under the Security tab.

Comment: That doesn't explain why he can access that folder for some time after rebooting the machine.